# Updated ActiveMQ Artemis and broker will not start

Tags: activemq-artemis

I updated ActiveMQ Artemis from 2.20.0 to 2.21.0. Now the broker will not start!

```
ERROR:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 44; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'broker'
java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
```

I moved the `<broker>` tag to line 20 in `bootstrap.xml` and it correspond to `lineNumber` in the error message.

Here's my `bootstrap.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<broker xmlns="activemq.org/schema">
   <jaas-security domain="activemq"/>
   <server configuration="${artemis.URI.instance}/etc/broker.xml"/> 
   <web bind="localhost:23161" path="web">
      <!-- <app url="jolokia" war="jolokia.war"/> --> 
      <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
      <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
      <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
   </web>
</broker>
```

Is this familiar to anyone?

Comment: Version 2.20.0 worked fine! No changes to bootstrap.xml.

Comment: Can you add your bootstrap.xml to the question?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.org/schema">
   <jaas-security domain="activemq"/>
   <server configuration="${artemis.URI.instance}/etc/broker.xml"/>
   <web bind="http://localhost:23161" path="web">
       <!--       <app url="jolokia" war="jolokia.war"/> -->
       <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
       <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
       <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
   </web>
</broker>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the upgrade instructions outlined in the [ActiveMQ Artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/versions.html#2210):

> Due to XML schema changes to correct an inaccurate domain name 2 files will need to be updated:
>
> 1. `etc/bootstrap.xml`
> 2. `etc/management.xml`
>
> In both files change the XML namespace from `activemq.org` to `activemq.apache.org`, e.g. in `bootsrap.xml` use:q:
>
> ```xml
> <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema">
> ```
>
> And in `management.xml` use:
>
> ```xml
> <management-context xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema">
> ```

Comment: Great! Working!